How to correctly configure a custom Statsd mapping yaml for a prometheus statsd exporter inside a docker compose service?
I have the following custom statsd yaml
mappings:
  - match: "*"
    observer_type: summary
    name: "stats"
    labels:
      timer: "$1"
    summary_options:
      quantiles:
        - quantile: 0.5
          error: 0.005
        - quantile: 0.75
          error: 0.0025
        - quantile: 0.95
          error: 0.01

which I'm mounting inside a docker compose service of prometheus's statds-exporter:
services:
  prometheus-statsd-exporter:
    image: prom/statsd-exporter:v0.26.0
    command: "--statsd.mapping-config=/tmp/statsd_mapping.yml"
    ports:
      - "9102:9102"
      - "9125:9125/udp"
    volumes:
      - './statsd.conf:/tmp/statsd_mapping.yml'

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.45.3
    command: "--config.file=/tmp/prometheus.yml --web.listen-address '0.0.0.0:9090'"
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - "./prometheus.yml:/tmp/prometheus.yml"

Which is then being scraped by prometheus:
global:
    scrape_interval:      15s
    evaluation_interval:  15s

scrape_configs:
    - job_name: "test"
      static_configs:
        - targets: ["prometheus-statsd-exporter:9102"]

I've been trying to follow the guidance for the setup through https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/statsd-exporter. From what i can tell via docker compose logs and by logging into the service, it appears like the yaml is in use as theres no errors coming from that command.
However, when I view my timer metrics in grafana, it appears that the quantiles are defaulting to 0.5, 0.9, & 0.99.
Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance
